# Faster array looping in React-Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, react-native, for-loop

Why cant I use this approach in React-Native for a faster looping:

```
var array = this.myinputfields.textfields.length;
for (let i = 0; i < array; i++)
```

I know this can be done in JavaScript but not in React-Native. Is there a way to loop faster through an array?

Comment: What is wrong with the approach? Any error message?

Comment: @BreakBB No errors, as I have mentioned I am just asking if there is another approach for a faster performance.

Comment: @BreakBB the one that I have posted doesnt work in React-Native, it throw error.

Comment: Can you describe the error ? Did you have any message ?

Comment: @R3tep it seems like I was wrong, it actually works. I tried it some days ago but it didnt, maybe there was another problem. However, what's your opinion, do you think this is a faster approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this faster way

```
for (let l = this.myinputfields.textfields.length; l--;) {}
```

But you loop on the array in reverse

Comment: can you explain why this is a faster way?

Comment: If you read the line, you can see there is one variable less and one operation less. There is only one incrementation and no comparison with `<`

Comment: When should I use this and when the other approach?

Comment: You can use this way if it's possible to loop on the array in reverse mode. The other one if it's not possible.